# Codeigniter 3.0 Count data by selecting year

Tags: codeigniter, count

In a table I have a date and amount columns with different dates and different amounts. so, Actually i want to display my data as

```
Select Year 
Month    Amount 


Total
```

But I got all years data and every month total

This is my model

```
public function overviews(){
   $sql = "SELECT DATEPART(Year, TRANS_TransactionDate) [TheYear], DATEPART(Month, TRANS_TransactionDate) [TheMonth], DATENAME(Month, TRANS_TransactionDate) [TheMonthName], SUM(Trans_Amount) [TotalAmount]
        FROM BTBL_Transactions
        GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, TRANS_TransactionDate), DATEPART(Month, TRANS_TransactionDate), DATENAME(Month, TRANS_TransactionDate)
        ORDER BY [TheYear], [TheMonth], [TheMonthName]";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
//echo $this->db->last_query(); die();
return $query->result();
}
```

And This is my controller

```
public function overviews(){
 //   $merchantid=$this->session->userdata('user_password');
   $result=$this->livemerchant_model->overviews();
    $name=$this->session->userdata('name');
           $data=array('result'=>$result,'name'=>$name);

   if($this->session->has_userdata('user_email','name')){
    $this->load->view('overviews.php', $data);


     }
   }
```

And this is my vie file

```
<?php 
foreach ($baji as $row) {?>
                                                                    <tr>


                                                                        <td><?php echo $row->TheMonthName . PHP_EOL;  ?></td>
                                                                        <td><?php echo $row->TotalAmount. PHP_EOL;?></td>

                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <?php }?>
```

Comment: I don't understand. What are you expecting, what is happening instead, and what have you tried?

Comment: want to display data by selecting year instead of all years records

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select by year, you'll want to include a `WHERE` statement in your sql.

```
SELECT...
WHERE YEAR = user_year_input_here
GROUP BY...
```